# how to create parentchild hierachery in ssrs single parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have one doubt in ssrs .
how to create parent hierachery in single parameter in ssrs with table report  using sql server database table.
table: empdetails:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empdetails](
    [empid] [int] NULL,
    [country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [state] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [empname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [deptno] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (1, N'india', N'ap', N'abc', 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (2, N'india', N'ka', N'def', 20)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (3, N'india', N'tn', N'de', 30)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (4, N'usa', N'TX', N'deet', 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (5, N'usa', N'NJ', N'ion', 60)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (6, N'usa', N'WV', N'xy', 70)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (7, N'uk', N'Belfast', N'io', 40)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empdetails] ([empid], [country], [state], [empname], [deptno]) VALUES (8, N'uk', N'Wycombe', N'un', 50)
GO
```

based on above table :  I want create parent hierrachery in singe paramerte like below in ssrs table report :
country....>State: drop down look like below:

```
paramername:countryandstateparamer:
                       india
                        ap
                        ka
                        tn
                      usa
                       nj
                       wv
                       tx
                       uk
                     Belfast
                     Wycombe
```

here If I select india then dispaly  corresponding states data (ap,ka,tn). 
     if I select  ap state then display only ap related data(ap)
     if  I select ap and ka state then display only ap and ka data( ap and ka)
 similay to other counry and states.

I tried like below : 
dataset : select * from empdetails where country in @country and  state in ( @state)

dataset 1: select distinct country  from empdetails
dataset2 : select distinct state from empdetails  where county=@country

after that I go throught  two paramerts mapping

here preview time I got two paramater one is country paramaterand 2nd is state  paramater.But I want only creat  only one paramater that parater show like counryandstate hierchar using sql server table data.

please tell me how to solve this issue in ssrs report multiple hieracher in single paramater .

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to build a hierarchy with SQL Server as the source (SSAS supports this though).

We can do with with a bit of code, the first part could be done using a view but this should work even though it seems like a lot of code, most of it is repeated (hence why a view would be better)

Anyway, 
First we need a dataset to supply data to the parameter list.

**First dataset**
Create a dataset called `dsRegions`
Set the dataset query to be

```
/* This could be built as a view to simplfy things */
-- create a table for the results
DECLARE @regions TABLE(RegionDisplayName varchar(50), RegionType varchar(1), RegionOrder decimal (10,3), RegionName varchar(50))

-- first get the countries in order and assign a sort order
INSERT INTO @regions
    SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY country) AS CountryOrder
            , country
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT Country, 'C' AS RegionType FROM empdetails) e

-- now get the states and assign the sort order from the country plus a sort oder for the state (supports 999 states/country)
INSERT INTO @regions
SELECT 
    '  ' + state, 'S' -- indent the states so they look better in the parameter list
    , RegionOrder + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.RegionName ORDER BY state) as decimal(10,3)) / 1000 AS StateOrder
    , state
 FROM @regions c
    JOIN empdetails e on c.RegionName = e.country

-- finally output the results
SELECT * FROM @regions order by regionorder
```

**Parameter** : let's call this `@pRegion`
So create a parameter called `pRegion` and set its available values dataset to `dsRegions`.

**important** Set the Value to `RegionName` and the label to `RegionDisplayName`

This will give us a nice ordered indented list for the user to see.

**Main dataset query**
The main dataset query repeats most of the parameter dataset query

The only difference is the final output which filters both country and state and if either match it will return the records. The query is as follows

```
-- create a table for the results
DECLARE @regions TABLE(RegionDisplayName varchar(50), RegionType varchar(1), RegionOrder decimal (10,3), RegionName varchar(50))

-- first get the countries in order and assign a sort order
INSERT INTO @regions
    SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY country) AS CountryOrder
            , country
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT Country, 'C' AS RegionType FROM empdetails) e

-- now get the states and assign the sort order from the country plus a sort oder for the state (supports 999 states/country)
INSERT INTO @regions
SELECT 
    '  ' + state, 'S' -- indent the states so they look better in the parameter list
    , RegionOrder + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.RegionName ORDER BY state) as decimal(10,3)) / 1000 AS StateOrder
    , state
 FROM @regions c
    JOIN empdetails e on c.RegionName = e.country

-- output
SELECT 
        e.*
    FROM empdetails e
    WHERE country in (@pRegion)
            or state in (@pRegion)
```

I've done a simple test and this works as expected, so if you select UK and TX you will get records for Belfast, Wycombe and TX

Hope this helps.